# ISO on hard drive boot install

Tags: system-installation, iso

I boot the iso on /dev/sda5 and want to install to /dev/sda2 (root) and /dev/sda6 (home)
I get an error, can't install cause /dev/sda5 is mounted
[image: 4 screen snapshots during install]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to boot with the boot option `toram`. It means that the mountpoint `/cdrom` will be pointing to a RAM drive, and I think it will be possible to unmount `/dev/sda5`.

Comment: what changes to grub2  initrd?                   40-custom:menuentry "Kubuntu 16.04.3 ISO" {
set isofile="/kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile} quiet splash
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz

Comment: You add the word `toram` to the 'linux' line `... quite splash ---` -->  `... quite splash toram ---` I don't think you need any change in the 'initrd' line. Do it live according to this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: If this does not work, I suggest that you make a boot drive from DVD disk or USB pendrive or memory card and boot from it instead. That will be straight-forward.

Comment: I found the same link, made the change on the fly and SUCCESS!! Thank you! works good. Installed without a problem

Comment: I'm glad it worked, congratulations :-) I will write a 'full answer' describing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Boot with the boot option **`toram`**

You want to install into a partition on the drive, that you are booting from via an iso file. The installer notices that there is a mounted partition, that it cannot unmount.

According to your uploaded screenshot, you need to unmount `/dev/sda5`, the mounted partition on the target drive for the installation.

In order to do that you should boot with the boot option **`toram`**. It means that the mountpoint `/cdrom` will be pointing to a RAM drive, and then it will be possible to unmount `/dev/sda5`.

Add the word 'toram' to the 'linux' line

```
linux ... quiet splash ---
```

-->

```
linux ... quiet splash toram ---
```

Do it live alias 'on the fly' by editing the syslinux or grub alternative according to this link,

[Try Ubuntu - Boot options](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808)